# LINQ add sum of columns to list entry

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum, .net-5

I'm currently working on a .net 5.0 application.

I need to use LINQ to do a complex query:

- Given is a `List<Player>`
- I need to transform the `List<Player>`, but keep all entries
- add the TotalScore for each Team to all Players in "SerieA"

Unfortunately I don't know how to properly calculate the TotalScore for each team for all Players in a league in C# LINQ extension method syntax.

- The player class:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Team  { get; set; }
    public int Score  { get; set; }
    public string League  { get; set; }
    public int TotalTeamScore  { get; set; }
}
```

- the program class

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // given is a List<Player> - I need to calculate the TotalScore for each team ONLY for Leage "SerieA"
        var players = new List<Player> {
            new Player { Name = "Alex", Team = "A", Score = 10, League = "SerieA", TotalTeamScore = 0 },
            new Player { Name = "Anna", Team = "A", Score = 20, League = "SerieA", TotalTeamScore = 0 },
            new Player { Name = "Berta", Team = "B", Score = 60, League = "SerieA", TotalTeamScore = 0 },
            new Player { Name = "Benny", Team = "B", Score = 40, League = "SerieA", TotalTeamScore = 0 },
            new Player { Name = "Charlie", Team = "C", Score = 40, League = "PremierLeague", TotalTeamScore = 0 },
            new Player { Name = "Connor", Team = "C", Score = 40, League = "PremierLeague", TotalTeamScore = 0 },
        };

        // I need to find a proper way to calculate the TotalTeamScore for each Team in league SerieA and add this score to the players...
        var teamTotalScores = players
                                .Where(p => p.League == "SerieA")
                                .GroupBy(p => p.Team)
                                .Select(p => new Player {
                                    TotalTeamScore = p.Sum(s => s.Score)
                                    // Score = x.Key ??
                                })
                                .ToList();
        
// desired result: same List<Player> - only the Total TeamScore of a Team in "SerieA" should be calculated for each team and added to each player in a team:
// new Player { Name = "Alex", Team = "A", Score = 10, League = "SerieA", TotalTeamScore = 30 },
// new Player { Name = "Anna", Team = "A", Score = 20, League = "SerieA", TotalTeamScore = 30 },
// new Player { Name = "Luke", Team = "B", Score = 60, League = "SerieA", TotalTeamScore = 100 },
// new Player { Name = "Lucy", Team = "B", Score = 40, League = "SerieA", TotalTeamScore = 100 },
        
// new Player { Name = "Charlie", Team = "C", Score = 40, League = "PremierLeague", TotalTeamScore = 0 },
// new Player { Name = "Connor", Team = "C", Score = 40, League = "PremierLeague", TotalTeamScore = 0 },
    }
```

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Do you know how to properly calculate the TotalScore for each team for all Players in a league in C# LINQ extension method syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ is designed for *querying*, whereas you need to modify the objects in the collection.

Whilst you could do this using `Enumerable.Select`, a standard `foreach` loop would be more appropriate:

```
var serieAPlayers = players.Where(p => p.League == "SerieA");

var teamScores = serieAPlayers
    .GroupBy(p => p.Team)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Sum(p => p.Score));

foreach (var player in serieAPlayers) player.TotalTeamScore = teamScores[player.Team];
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!! One little improvement perhaps, I had to check whether the key [player.Team] does exist in the dictionary. :)

Comment: Ah yes, the `foreach` should only iterate over the players in Serie A; I'll update the answer.